# Is there any convention for where one stores installed software?

Tags: darwin

I'm installing some software by cloning a git repo onto my local machine. I plan on creating a soft link to the binary made from the source in the repo to  `/usr/local/bin`. Where should I put the git repo on my local machine? Is `/usr/local/src` the place?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this question "Darwin", I assume you use macOS. In which case, Xcode clones repositories by default to `~/Documents`.

Another convention used to be used by System V, was to create individual project (or application distribution) directories in `/opt`. MacPorts does store its working directories in `/opt/local` by the way.

The ["File Hierarchy Standard"](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) has other recommendations.